# GWTP Compile Error Rest-Dispatch

Tags: rest, gwt, ant, ivy, gwtp

I am having trouble with GWTP Rest-Dispatch, when I include the Rest-Dispatch configurations (as stated in the wiki) these compiler errors: http://pastebin.com/eWNg2c94 (compile log)

I have no idea what is causing this, I am using Ivy dependency manager (IvyDE eclipse). I have verified all the gwtp-rest dependencies exist. I am using both Dispatchers (Rpc/Rest) here is my applications gwt module configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="ims">
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />

    <extend-property name="locale" values="en"></extend-property>

    <!-- Core module inherits -->
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.framework.module.Framework" />
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.ims.Resources" />

    <!-- Theme module inherits -->
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.framework.themes.SyrenaTheme"/>

    <!-- GXT -->
    <!--stylesheet src="reset.css" /-->
    <!--inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' /-->

    <!-- GXT Theme -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.blue.Blue'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.gray.Gray' /> -->
    <!--inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme" /-->

    <!-- Library module inherits -->
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.DispatchRest"/>
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.DispatchRpc"/>
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.query.Query"/>

    <inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3CDN"/>
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.framework.extensions.gwtbootstrap3.datepicker.Datepicker"/>

    <inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt.Client"/>

    <replace-with class="org.atmosphere.gwt.client.impl.IEHTMLFileCometTransport">
      <when-type-is class="org.atmosphere.gwt.client.impl.CometTransport"/>
      <any>
        <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
        <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie8"/>
        <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie9"/>
      </any>
    </replace-with>

    <!-- Framework module inherits -->
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.framework.libraries.maydu.validation.ValidationLibrary" />
    <inherits name="nz.co.doltech.framework.libraries.chosen.Chosen" />

    <!-- Module entry point -->
    <entry-point class="nz.co.doltech.ims.client.Application"/>

    <extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules" 
        value="nz.co.doltech.ims.client.gin.ClientModule" />

    <set-configuration-property name="gwtp.bootstrapper"  
         value="nz.co.doltech.ims.client.BootstrapperImpl"/>

    <set-configuration-property name="gwtp.prebootstrapper"  
         value="nz.co.doltech.ims.client.BootstrapperImpl.PreBootstrapperImpl"/>

    <extend-configuration-property name="document.compatMode" value="BackCompat" />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared" />

    <generate-with class="com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.FixedUiBinderGenerator">
        <when-type-assignable class="com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder"/>
    </generate-with>

    <!-- RPC Serialization Ignores -->
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="javax.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.query.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.aria.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.dom.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.validation.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="nz.co.doltech.framework.extensions.gwtbootstrap3.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="nz.co.doltech.framework.libraries.maydu.validation.client.*"/>
    <extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="nz.co.doltech.framework.themes.syrena.ui.*"/>
</module>
```

My ANT build script:

```xml
  <!--
  ================================
     Build Application Binaries
  ================================
  -->

  <target name="javac" depends="tests" description="Compile java source">
    <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8" destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes" source="1.7" target="1.7"
        nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
      <classpath refid="tomcat.libs"/>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
      <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java" />
      <fileset dir="resources" excludes="**/*.java" />
      <fileset dir="database" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" maxmemory="512m">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      </classpath>
      <arg value="-war"/>
      <arg value="war"/>

      <!--arg value="-strict" /-->

      <!-- Logging level arguments -->
      <!--arg value="-logLevel" />
      <arg value="ERROR" /-->

      <!-- Optimization arguments -->
      <!--arg value="-XenableClosureCompiler"/>
      <arg value="-XdisableClassMetadata"/-->

      <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>

      <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
      <arg value="nz.co.doltech.framework.module.Framework"/>
      <arg value="nz.co.doltech.framework.login.Login"/>
      <arg value="nz.co.doltech.ims.Ims"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="build" depends="gwtc" description="Build web application entry point"/>
```

If anyone else has had similar problems I would really really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using MvpWithEntryPoint but your own entry point, so you need to tell GIN to load the generated modules. Can you make sure your Ginjector looks like the one described here: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Rest-Dispatch#installing-with-your-own-ginjector

MOre specifically, in the @GinModules you need to add this argument: `properties = {"gin.ginjector.modules"}` and the following method to your interface: `RestDispatch getRestDispatch();`

Comment: Where do I initialize my ginjector? I didn't have one previously, so I am adding it now and not sure exactly how to initialize it. The bootstrapping wiki page doesn't specify.

Comment: Removed my entry point and added MvpWithEntryPoint and still getting this error.